# Check for 6 or more consecutive numbers in a column in oracle sql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need help with a query to identify unstructured data. I need to identify all the rows which have more than 6 consecutive numbers in their data. I know we can use regular expressions like ^[0-9] for the same.

For example:

I have a column named Address. The address column may contain 6 or more consecutive numbers. I need to identify which rows contain more than 6 consecutive numbersi in them.

```
675467 should be the output
67433232 should be the output
4453 should not be the output.
```

Comment: Can this column contain other data? Or only numbers? If only numbers, can there be spaces between them?

Comment: `where regexp_like(address, '\d{6}')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second Egor Skriptunoff, you can the answer on this demo on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/304c9/1)